# Proving there is a unique solution to a multiplicative functional equation

Tags: functions

I am trying to find all solutions $f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that
$f(f(x))*(f(x))^2=1/x$ and $f>0\quad  \forall x>0$.

I guessed a solution of the form $$x^\gamma \implies (x^\gamma)^\gamma*(x^\gamma)^2=1/x \implies x^{\gamma^2+2\gamma}=x^{-1}\implies x^{\gamma^2+2\gamma+1}=1 \implies x^{(\gamma+1)^2}=1 \implies \gamma=-1\implies f(x)=1/x$$ is the unique solution among power functions.  I suspect that this function is the unique solution among all $f$ although I am not sure how to prove this.  If it is not unique, what other functions satisfy the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some additional assumption (eg continuity) there are many other solutions. For convenience let
$$
  g(x)=\ln f(e^x).
$$
Then the problem is equivalent to finding a function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ satisfying
$$
  g(g(x))+2g(x)+x=0.
$$
Choose any nonzero $a\in\mathbb R$. Let
$$
  g(x)=\begin{cases}
    ((-1)^n-n)a&\text{if }x=na\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb Z,\\
    -x&\text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$$
Then
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  g(g(na))+2g(na)+na
    &=&\left[(-1)^{n+1}-((-1)^n-n)\right]a+2\left[(-1)^n-n\right]a+na\\
    &=&0,
\end{eqnarray*}$$
and if $x\notin\mathbb Z a$,
$$
  g(g(x))+2g(x)+x=-(-x)+2x+x=0.
$$
Thus we have constructed a distinct solution for each $a\in\mathbb R^*$ (there are probably others).